# Console host for WCF web service shutting down

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services

I have this console host for my WCF web service 
PROGRAM.CS

```
 class Program
     {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WebServiceHost Host = new WebServiceHost(typeof(Service1));

            try
            {
                Host.Open();
                Console.ReadLine();
                Host.Close();
            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                Host.Abort();
            }

        }
```

This is my app.config for the host

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="Csvpost.Service1">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8000/"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup>
</configuration>
```

This is Service1 class for the service

```
   public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public Stream HandleMessage(Stream request)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(request);
            string text = reader.ReadToEnd();
            System.Text.ASCIIEncoding encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(encoding.GetBytes(text));
            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "text/html";
            string[] sites = text.Split('\n');
            int y = sites.Length;
            int i;
            for (i = 0; i < y; i++)
            {
                /logic/
                System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con;
                System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd;
                con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(connection);
                cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(query, con);
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
            }
            return ms;
        }
    }
```

My host is shutting down as soon as it starts running. what mistake have I done?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the service host in the same project as your WCF Service?

Comment: I have that already in my try block.

Comment: I would expect that if it were shutting down prematurely, it would be because of a bad app.config, or an unhandled exception in the first line of `Main`. Either way, the console app should emit exception information.

Comment: @Preben Huybrechts No I have added a new project called Console host and than setted it as the start up project.

Comment: @HackedByChinese Yaa but its just shutting down with no exceptions being displayed.

Comment: Are you starting Visual Studio as administrator or as a regular user?

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to start a WebServiceHost in a console.  You need to start a ServiceHost.  That is also possibly why you are not getting an error message as WebServiceHost would not write to the console.

And you are not attaching the service to the port in the config.  This is a console host that is working for me.

```
<services>
  <service name="MajicEightBallServiceLib.MagicEightBallService"
           behaviorConfiguration="EightBallServiceMEXBehavior" >
    <endpoint address=""
              binding="wsHttpBinding"
              contract="MajicEightBallServiceLib.IEightBall" />
    <endpoint address="mex"
              binding ="mexHttpBinding"
              contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8000/MagicEightBallService"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>             
  </service>
</services>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using Trace option of WCF. It will log the error for you. Your application is getting prematurely terminated. Trace will help you to identify the issue.